# Discord.js showing "message.author.tag | message.content"

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

So I am making a bot that when it gets dmed it logs to a channel, the problem is, the message coming to the channel is showing "message.author.tag | message.content" instead of the user dming and what they said. I'm sure this is an easy fix but I can't find it in the docs.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.channel.type === "dm" && message.author.id !== client.user.id) {
    client.channels.cache.get('789752010572169216').send(`message.author.tag | message.content`);
}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use backticks for a string you're making a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). The way to [interpolate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation), or insert values in template literals is to wrap them in `${}`.

So you can change the message to something like this:

```
`${message.author.tag} | ${message.content}`
```